# How to add multiple domains to one certificate in gcp and point to a load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a compute engine with a simple page builder, on this server I can have several domains pointed to, currently I create a new SSL certificate with the domains I want, ex: example1.com, example2.com and etc... Then I access the load balancer and edit the frontend settings and add the new certificate that I generated. :

existing domains: example 1.com, example2.com
new domain: example3.com

What I have to add when generating the ssl are the three example1.com, example2.com,example3.com

Is there another way to do this?

[page for create certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f2Xr.png)

[current certificated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kne1V.png)

[where I add new certificates or update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rb0V.png)

Comment: Google free certificates are mapped to only one domain so the answer is no. The other option is that you own a wildcard certificate but only will apply to subdomains of a single root domain.

Comment: Add multiple certificates to the load balancer. Google HTTP Load Balancers support more than one certificate (purchased and Google managed).

Comment: @JohnHanley that's what I do, but it's very costly, and every time I add a new domain, I have to change the load balancer to use the new certificate, and that generates a minute of offline application, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. In the question there are the prints...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you mean that you want "instant" certificate deployment? I am not aware of a Google-managed service that can instantly deploy a certificate. There will be some downtime while the frontend reconfigures. You could use multiple load balancers pointing to the same backend. New domain/certificate, add a new load balancer.

Comment: @JohnHanley 
I can't add a new load balancer targeted to the same ip.

Error: Invalid value for field 'resource.IPAddress': 'projects/teste-375613/global/addresses/ulink-load-balancer'. Specified IP address is in-use and would result in a conflict.

Comment: @AlessandroPrudencio not enough details so that I understand what you are doing. Create a new question and let me know the link.

Comment: @JohnHanley I created it, follow the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76597250/how-to-have-multiple-certificates-for-a-loadbalancer