# how to have multiple certificates for a loadbalancer?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, certbot, gcp-load-balancer

Currently, my infrastructure consists of a Compute Engine with an Apache2 server and a PHP website. In this PHP site, it's possible to have multiple users, and each user can have a customized domain and a specific page.

I configured a Load Balancer, defining the HTTPS protocol, and pointed it to my VM. In the certificate section, I created a new certificate (*client-certificates*) provided by Cloud Load Balancing and added all the desired domains to it: client1.com, client2.com, client3.com.

So far, everything is working perfectly. However, the issue arises when a new client wants to have a certificate for their own domain, for example, client4.com. The steps I have to take are as follows:

1. Delete the existing client certificates since they cannot be edited.
2. Create a new certificate named *client-certificates-v2* and add the new domain to it, resulting in: client1.com, client2.com, client3.com, client4.com.

However, when I delete the old certificate, all other clients with domains immediately lose their secure connection, and it takes some time for the new certificate to propagate. Based on my experience, this can take about 30 minutes.

Is there another way to do this without affecting clients who already have certificates? I'm new to this area, and I may be missing some steps. I'm open to ideas, criticisms, and links to understand what I need to do and better comprehend this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to delete the current certificate. Create a new certificate and add that to the certificate list. See this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#multiplessl).

The maximum number of Google-managed certificates is 100. Each forwarding rule can have 1-14 additional certificates. See this [document](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/quotas#resource_quotas) for more details on quotas.

Comment: I tried to add the certificate to my load balancer after it was created, but I get this error:

_Invalid value for field 'resource.IPAddress': 'projects/tt-375613/global/addresses/tt-load-balancer'. Specified IP address is in-use and would result in a conflict_.

Here is the screen print where I added a new certificate:
[image](https://imgbox.com/SuHasBAP)

Locale create new certificate:
[Locale create new certificate](https://imgbox.com/lSJgcKzC)

Comment: @AlessandroPrudencio - You are creating a new frontend which is not necessary. Add the certificate to the existing frontend. The document link shows you how.

Comment: I am unable to add a new one to the front end, I can only replace it as I described in the question. However, I don't want to replace it, I want to add a new one that I created following your suggestion. https://imgbox.com/txRNsoUw.

i maybe my load balancer type is wrong ? I'm like HTTP(S)

Comment: @AlessandroPrudencio - I tested adding an additional certificate this afternoon. Make sure that you are selecting the existing Frontend. Scroll down to `ADDITIONAL CERTIFICATES`. Expand and select ADD CERTIFICATE. Adding a new certificate did not cause downtime on the existing certificate endpoints during my testing.

Comment: @AlessandroPrudencio - The option is one inch below where your screenshot shows `Certificate`. Look for that down arrow in your screen behind the popup in your screenshot.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I didn't realize I had to click on the "Other certificates" option. I thought the down arrow meant that the SSL policy options for QUIC negotiation were already there. But then I realized that clicking on it would expand the options. Honestly, if it hadn't said "ADDITIONAL CERTIFICATES," I would never have clicked on it. Thank you so much, and I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: @AlessandroPrudencio - I think that part of the GUI needs improvement. If you know the UI, then it is obvious, but how often do we create load balancers?